# How to send broadcast to all connected client in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

I'm a newbie working with an application with MEAN stack. It is an IoT based application and using nodejs as a backend.

I have a scenario in which I have to send a broadcast to each connected clients which can only open the Socket and can wait for any incoming data. unless like a web-browser they can not perform any event and till now I have already gone through the `Socket.IO` and `Express.IO` but couldn't find anything which can be helpful to achieve what I want `send raw data to open socket connections`'

Is there any other Node module to achieve this. ?

Here is the code using WebSocketServer,

```
    const express = require('express');
    const http = require('http');
    const url = require('url');
    const WebSocket = require('ws');

    const app = express();

    app.use(function (req, res) {
      res.send({ msg: "hello" });
    });

    const server = http.createServer(app);
    const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ server });

   wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
     ws.on('message', function(message) {
       wss.broadcast(message);
     }
   }

   wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg) {
     console.log(msg);
     wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
       client.send(msg);
     });
    };

    server.listen(8080, function listening() {
      console.log('Listening on %d', server.address().port);
    });
```

Now, my query is when this code will be executed,

```
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
       wss.broadcast(message);
    }
 }
```

Comment: you can use websocket broadcast method

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var WebSocketServer = require("ws").Server;

var wss = new WebSocketServer({port:8100});

wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
    ws.on('message', function(message) {
       wss.broadcast(message);
    }

}

wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg) {
   console.log(msg);
   wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
       client.send(msg);
    });
};
```

Comment: when will be the `connection` event will be triggered ?

Comment: save this code with .js extenstion like 'server.js', run using node command like 'node server.js'

Comment: as per your new code, and query, that part of code says that, when websocket connection is on and when it receives any message, then it pass that message to broadcast function, then broadcast function send/broadcast to all clients which are cnnected

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to broadcast message from server to every client.

```
wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
    client.send(data.toString());
});
```

Demo server code,

```
const WebSocket = require('ws')
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: 2055 },()=>{
    console.log('server started')
})
wss.on('connection', (ws) => {
   ws.on('message', (data) => {
      console.log('data received \n '+ data)
      wss.clients.forEach(function(client) {
         client.send(data.toString());
      });
   })
})
wss.on('listening',()=>{
   console.log('listening on 2055')
})
```