# error: Typeerror: wss.broadcast in not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, ws

I made a chat app and I am trying to broadcast the message, but I am getting this error: "error: Typeerror: wss.broadcast in not a function".

this is the server code:

```
const WebSocket = require('ws');
let broadcast_msg;

const PORT = 5000;
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({
  port: PORT
});

wss.on("connection", (ws) =>{
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message){
    console.log('received: ', message);
    wss.broadcast(message)

  });
});

console.log("Server is liestening on port " + PORT);
```

Comment: Hope this question resolves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301672/how-to-send-broadcast-to-all-connected-client-in-node-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I am currently doing as well

```
wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg){
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client){
    client.send(msg);
  });
};
```

But this also give me back multiple responses depending on my number of clients.  Does anyone know how to prevent this?

Answer (score 0):

Because Class: WebSocket.Server don't have broadcast function,you can read [ws api](https://github.com/websockets/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md) to confirm.

You can foreach wss.clients to send meesages one by one to broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

I change my code to that:

```
wss.on("connection", (ws) =>{
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message){
    console.log('received: ', message);
    wss.broadcast(message);
 });
});

wss.broadcast = function broadcast(msg){
  wss.clients.forEach(function each(client){
    client.send(msg);
  });
};
```